# Java - Possible that socket data transfer is blocked by too little memory?

Tags: java, sockets, memory, tcp, timeout

I'm testing my software (several applications) on a Vserver. All applications are connected to a central server using TCP. But after some hours they all time out which means that they no longer send the keep alive packet. Actually they do, but it does not arrive at the server.
Some seconds after this the application that timed out exits with an OutOfMemoryError.

So is it possible that also the socket communication between the applications was "blocked" because of too less memory?

Edit: Usually the exception before the OOME is an IOException with Broken Pipe.

Comment: What makes you sure that they really send the packets before they die?

Comment: @McMonster If they hadn't sent the keep alive packets, it would have thrown an error or something like that.

Comment: Where would that error be thrown? In failing clients? Please be more specific. TCP does not implement any form of keep-alive itself, so it may only detect a failure if the other side does not acknowledge that it received the data and this depends on frequency of transmissions between your applications and ACK timeout. It is perfectly reasonable to assume that the only existing problem is the OOME.

Comment: @McMonster TCP does indeed implement a keepalive, but it is off by default.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the *relevant* exception is the broken pipe. That means you have written to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. In other words, an application protocol error.

The rest of your post is mere guesswork. Clearly you have a memory leak somewhere, and an application protocol mis-implementation. Find them and fix them.